# Data not showing using datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using a datatables to get data from database. The problem i am facing is that the controller method to get data is working properly and returning DataSet which i can see in xhr but the data is not showing in html page. I can't figure out the problem. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.
Here is my code snippet.

```
<table   id="DbTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


</table>
```

Script code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCompanies", "Company")',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#DbTable').DataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
                         { "data": "Id" },
                           { "data": "Name" },
                           { "data": "Email" },
                            { "data": "Address" },
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetCompanies()
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Company> company = _companyService.GetCompanies().ToList();
            IEnumerable<CompanyListViewModel> viewModelListCompanies = Mapper.DynamicMap<IEnumerable<Company>, IEnumerable<CompanyListViewModel>>(company);


            return new JsonSuccessResult(viewModelListCompanies);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)ResponseCode.UnprocessableEntity;
            return new JsonErrorResult(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

JsonSuccessResult Class:

```
public class JsonSuccessResult : JsonResult
{
    public JsonSuccessResult()
    {
        Data = new { Success = true, Error = false, Message = "Data has been saved successfully" };
        ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }
    public JsonSuccessResult(MessageCode messageCode)
    {
        Data = new { Success = true, Error = false, Message = MessageDictionary.SuccessMessages[messageCode] };
        ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }

    public JsonSuccessResult(string message)
    {
        Data = new { Success = true, Error = false, Message = message };
        ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }

    public JsonSuccessResult(IEnumerable enumerable, long totalCount = 0, int limit = 50, int offset = 0)
    {
        Data = new
        {
            Success = true,
            Error = false,
            Message = "Success",
            DataSet = enumerable,
            Limit = limit,
            Offset = offset,
            TotalCount = totalCount,
        };
        ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }
    public JsonSuccessResult(object data)
    {
        Data = new
        {
            Success = true,
            Error = false,
            Message = "Success",
            Data = data
        };
        ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }
    public JsonSuccessResult(int val)
    {
        Data = new
        {
            Success = true,
            Error = false,
            Message = "Success",
            Data = val
        };
        ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is a `JsonSuccessResult`?  I searched for it and only see it in other SO questions with code very similar to yours.  If it puts the results in a property like `data` instead of just returning the raw array, you will need to adjust the JS accordingly.

Comment: JsonSuccessResult is a class which uses enums and dictionaries to return success message if the requested operation is completed successfully.

Comment: So what does the returned JSON *look like*?

Comment: I have updated the code with that class as well

Comment: returned Json Dataset is as follows:
DataSet
:
[{Id: 1, Name: "imran", Owner: "sd", Email: "bc130403039@vu.edu.pk"}]
0
:
{Id: 1, Name: "imran", Owner: "sd", Email: "bc130403039@vu.edu.pk"}
Email
:
"bc130403039@vu.edu.pk"
Id
:
1
Name
:
"imran"
Owner
:
"sd"
Error
:
false
Limit
:
50
Message
:
"Success"
Offset
:
0
Success
:
true
TotalCount
:
0

Comment: So you need `data: data.DataSet, columns: [...` instead of `data: data, columns: [...` because it puts the ienumerable in a property called `DataSet`.

Comment: Thanks bro. This is working now. Please add this as your answer so that i mark your answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returned `JsonSuccessResult` object isn't an array, it's an object that has the data in a property called `DataSet`.  So you need to change

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#DbTable').DataTable({
        data: data,
```

to

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#DbTable').DataTable({
        data: data.DataSet,
```